# what's wrong if I initialize a class member List outside of the constructor in java

Tags: java

here is my code:

```
     A.java
****************
Public class A {
  List<String> member;  
}

    Main.java
****************
public void main() {
  List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
  l.add("apple");
  l.add("balala");
  A a = new A();
  a.member = l;

  for (String s : a.member)
    system.println(s);
  } 
}
```

Then I get **Java Null pointer error**

On the other hand, If I do `new a.member` in the constructor of `class A`. Then everything is fine.

So what's wrong with the above code? (`target Array can not be copied without initialization`)?

Comment: first correct all the compilation error in you code second make youself more clearer

Comment: Where do you have something like `A a = new A();`?

Comment: What is `a`? Where did you declare and initialize it?

Comment: Your posted code shouldn't even compile much less throw a NPE. You never declare the `a` variable anywhere before using it. In the future, please post short but complete and real code, not kind-of sort-of code, as this helps minimize confusion and helps get better and quicker answers.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put A a = new A(); on the post. It is in my code and it compiles correctly. But I will get Nullpointer error in run time.

Comment: Then please edit your question and show the real code.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Post code which will compile and which will throw NPE.

Comment: which line has the NPE? And how exactly can you fix it with "new a.member"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are creating "a". You need something like:

```
public void main() {
  List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
  l.add("apple");
  l.add("balala");
  A a = new A();
  a.member = l;

  for (String s : a.member)
    system.println(s);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put that line "A a = new A();"in post here. It is in the code and it compiles. So why there is runtime Null Pointer error?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing non static member variable from another class so you have to create a object to access that variable.

In your case, it will be `A a = new A();`

**Main.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add("apple");
        l.add("balala");
        A a = new A();
        a.member = l;

        for (String s : a.member) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
class A {
    List<String> member;
}
```